# How to change drive/partition icons in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, icons

I want to change the default .desktop icon. I know how but i dont know where is the original .desktop file located.

Comment: Right click the file, go into Properties, and you'll see the original path there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all the `*.desktop` files in your system do:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname *.desktop
```

Common locations:

```
/usr/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications
~/.gnome/apps
```

But in your case you are not looking for `*.desktop` files as because these files exist only for **installed applications** not for system drives and system partitions.

What you are looking for are the icons present in:

```
/usr/share/icons/*
```

Comment: i know but how is it named? i can't find it